# R2DBC adjacency list get all children

Tags: postgresql, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I have a table which has `id` and `parentId` columns: i refer to this structure as an adjacency list.
So, now i want to get all children of arbitrary id. Classic solution of this problem use recursion, for example [here is Postgres procedure or CTE implementation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_list_of_all_children_from_adjacency_tree).

I'm currently using Spring Webflux and Spring Data R2DBC + Postgres R2DBC driver (which doesn't support stored procedures yet).
How can i approach this problem in reactive style? Is it even possible or am i missing something conceptually wrong?

UPD 1:
Let's image we've data like:

```
+-------------+---------+
|id           |parent_id|
+-------------+---------+
|root         |NULL     |
|id1          |root     |
|dir1         |root     |
|dir1_id1     |dir1     |
|dir1_dir1    |dir1     |
|dir1_dir1_id1|dir1_dir1|
+-------------+---------+
```

Now i want to have a method inside a *ReactiveCrudRepository*, which will return all children of provided id.

For example, using sample data: by providing id='dir1', i want to get children with ids: ['dir1_id1', "dir1_dir1", "dir1_dir1_id1"].

Comment: if you still can use recursive cte , you don't need proc necessarily

Comment: @eshirvana, yes, i can, but CTE from PG Wiki involves full scan (select * from t) of a table, which is probably only a temporary solution. In my use case adjacency list table might be quite big (> 10k rows).

Comment: You better ask a better question with exactly what you want

Comment: I mean provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using proc or cte has nothing to do with full scan.

in your case scenario, you only have to use recursive cte , but adding an index on id, parentid will surely help

```
create index idx_name on tablename (parentid , id);
```

also 10k rows its not that big , index will definitely improve cte alot.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best sql approach is recursive CTE (Common Table Expressions), did you try it? I never tried it with many rows.

```
WITH recursive nodes AS (
   SELECT id, parent_id
   FROM t
   WHERE parent_id = 'dir1'
   
   UNION ALL
   
   SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
   FROM nodes n
   INNER JOIN t ON t.parent_id = n.id
)

SELECT id 
FROM nodes;
```

Output for parent_id = 'dir1'

| id |
| --- |
| dir1_id1 |
| dir1_dir1 |
| dir1_dir1_id1 |